# How do I reduce crashes during MP load games in Civilization 5?

Tags: civilization-5

During playing MP games with my friends, there is about 70% chance that we will not be able to load save game. This means that we need to start game from scratch. Loading older saves also result in fatal exception. Is there some way to increase chances of successful loading in MP games?

Single-player saves work without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

More then likely this is an issue that is unsolvable as it could be a bug in the game. although you asked this question a year ago so im guessing the issue has been fixed by now as im sure you are not the only one experiencing it from what i remember of some of the older bugs in Civ 5

possibly try playing with fewer players/computers or smaller maps and reduce the amount of autosaves as well.

Answer (score -2):

To solve this problem you can try running the game in DirectX 9 mode. If that doesn't work there are other solutions that have worked for other people.

You can find instructions for fixing Civilization 5 freezing and crashing here: http://www.thefakegeek.com/2013/12/how-to-stop-civilization-v-from-freezing-and-crashing/